# ES6 Set setting but "size" not changing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using ES6's new **Set** type/object and I'm running into a very odd problem where when I add an item to the set it shows up as part the `<entries>` but the size doesn't shift from zero:

[image: console.log]

To give a bit more context, here's the code that initially sets up the code:

```
selectedValues: on('init',computed('group.selected', {
  set: function(param,value) {
    return typeOf(value) === 'array' ? new Set(value) : new Set([value]);
  },
  get: function() {
    return new Set();
  }
}))
```

> Note: this is an Ember computed property for those of you not familiar with the syntax

and here's the code that is adding/deleting elements of the set:

```
  if(selectedValues.has(elementId)) {
    selectedValues.delete(elementId);
  } else {
    selectedValues.add(elementId);
  }
```

At any point in execution I can see from the console that the item is being added and removed from the Set but the size property is not effected. At the same time if I run the same set of commands from the browser's console it *does* work.

For those familiar, I am using Babel via the `ember-cli-babel` plugin. I have tried this problem both with and without the **includePolyfill** option (aka, including -- or not -- Babel's browser polyfill).

Comment: your getter is always returning a `new Set()` - which would have length 0

Comment: actually your setter is also invalid according to the ES6 spec, it should have exactly one parameter, yours has two

Comment: the getter is cached, so it only returns the empty set the first time. This is a standard approach in Ember computed properties

Comment: in what way does my setter have two parameters? It only has one: `elementId`, right?

Comment: Not super familiar with Ember, but are you trying to observe the size of the computed property's `size` somewhere? Ember has overridden the `size` getter and setter functions, so the size will probably just always be whatever it was at the start.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yeah I was trying to use the size as a property of the Set to detect changes to the set but you are probably right that the attribute is getting cached by Ember.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on http://emberjs.jsbin.com please? It has the Babel option.

Comment: I must be reading it wrong - the `set: function(param,value) {` looks like a setter with 2 parameters, but you mention that is some Ember thing, so I guess that must be altered some way before it's spat out as javascript

Comment: Here's an example: http://ember-twiddle.com/7db9227b30012b67de24

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah that's the default signature passed into a computed property :)